# Symfony test fail to access to repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, functional-testing, symfony4

I am using Symfony 4 and I have a functional test where I need to access to my database. But when this is executed:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);
```

I have this output:

> App\Tests\Controller\AppControllerTest::testPostSubmit
>   Error: Call to undefined method App\Tests\Controller
>   \AppControllerTest::getDoctrine()

This is my `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="APP_SECRET" value="s$cretf0rt3st" />
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
        <env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/haytest" />
        <!-- define your env variables for the test env here -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>./src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

And this is my test (it's not done):

```
/**
 * Test the submitting of posts
 */
public function testPostSubmit()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);

    if (!$this->getUser()) {
        if (!$repository->find(1)) {
            $user = new User;

            $user->setFirstName('root');
            $user->setLastName('root');
            $user->setUsername('root');
            $user->setEmail('root@root.root');
            $user->setPassword(password_hash('root', PASSWORD_ARGON2I));

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $loginpage = $client->request('GET', '/en/login');
        $form = $loginpage->selectButton('submit')->form();
        $form['username'] = 'root';
        $form['password'] = 'root';
        $client->submit($form);
    }

    // We request the app_index controller.
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/en/');

    // We verify that we have a 200 status code.
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
```

I really don't understand why it's not working...

Comment: Where do you define `getDoctrine()`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you, according to Symfony's documentation, [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database), we don't have to define `getDoctrine()`.

Comment: This part of the documentation refers to a `Controller` based class, and the `Controller` parent class indeed does have a function `getDoctrine()`. However, if you write Test classes, you're not inheriting from `Controller`, do you?

Comment: Indeed, my class don't inherit from Controller, then, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test class inherits from `KernelTestCase`, you can retrieve the `EntityManager` object via the `Kernel` class in the setup function:

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
private $entityManager;

public function setUp()
{
    $kernel = self::bootKernel();
    $this->entityManager = $kernel
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();
}
```

If your class inherits from `WebTestCase`, you can also retrieve the `EntityManager`object via the `Client` instance in the setup function:

```php
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
private $entityManager;

public function setUp()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $this->entityManager = $client
        ->getContainer()
        ->get('doctrine')
        ->getManager();
}
```

Check out [this part](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/doctrine.html) of the Symfony documentation for more information on testing Doctrine repositories.

Comment: Already tested that, but the test class HAVE to extends from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` (else, `$client = static::createClient();` don't work). Also, that's the definition of WebTestCase: `abstract class WebTestCase extends KernelTestCase`.

Comment: Try `$client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();`

Comment: `App\Tests\Controller\AppControllerTest::testPostSubmit Error: Call to undefined method App\Tests\Controller \AppControllerTest::getContainer()` XD!

Comment: You need to work with the `$client` instance: `$client = static::createClient(); $entityManager = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();`

Comment: Thank you, it now works! I have another problem (with `$this->getUser()`) but I think I will find the solution myself ;)! Thank you very much!